# Are these signs of bad management/bad workplace culture or am I exaggerating?

Tags: workplace-rhythm

I am working at a small company in Spain as a full-stack software developer and I accumulated a lot of what I would call red flags, to the point where I'm evaluating leaving the company and looking for something else.

I am a junior developer with 1.5 years of experience, that I spent in this company entirely.
Here is a list of things that in my opinion were/are not good. I want to understand if I'm overreacting and should accept that it's the same in every other company as well, or if I have some chances of finding a better place.

1. The very first day I started the job I was assigned some tasks, using a framework they knew I didn't know, to complete in 5 days. The week after that they showed the result to the customer.
2. Whenever I got a task, 8 times out of 10 it was poorly explained (like 10 minutes of explaining and then they were in a hurry for something else), and I had to reach out again to have clearance on some aspects.
3. In 1.5 years of work, I worked on approximately 15 projects. I was never given the time to get familiar with the codebase of any project: they expected me to solve bugs the day after they assigned me the project.
4. After 8 months of experience, I was given a project to start from scratch and carry out all by myself, with a tight deadline. The problem was that I didn't know anything about the main backend framework I was supposed to use (by requirement). In general, I am never given the time to learn anything, not even for a week before starting to code. I learned the framework while coding, but it was not easy given the deadline coming really fast.
5. I am under 2 different managers with deadlines over deadlines. They never communicate between each other (even if the company is small) to understand if my workload is compatible with new tasks, they just shove them to me. When I really have too much stuff to do I tell them to give me some time before assigning the task, but I feel bad and I'm afraid I look like a lazy/slow worker.
6. There are no code reviews nor salary reviews. For all I know, I may have written bad code all along, and no one has told me because there's simply no time to check junior devs' code. Of course I try to write good code, but I cannot fully evaluate myself.
7. I am paid less than average for my area (south of Spain) and my experience level.

I can go on, but I just quoted the first things that came to mind. I get that there's a lot of work to get done, but I often get very anxious because I feel like I don't have time to properly write some decent code, and this means just more technical debt and more work to do in the future.
The same things happen to my coworkers as well, I'm not the only one saying those things.
What would you do in my shoes? Would you consider leaving?

Comment: I think this is largely opinion based. If you should consider leaving is something you need to decide yourself. Get some interviews and look what you can get. All points are stuff that happens in a lot of companies. What you can do about them: Communicate. Never shut up because you are afraid of looking "dumb" or "lazy". If you don't communicate, it will never get better.

Comment: Sounds like a regular first job

Answer (score 8):

Broadly, they seem like bad management, but on some points it's hard to tell.

Points 1-4 could be bad management, but could also be an expectation that you learn on the fly while doing the work. You were able to complete the work, ask questions and get the work shown to customers, after all. Only you can know whether this management is over the line.

Point 5 is clearly bad management. Multiple managers is even a punchline in Office Space. That they do not communicate with each other before dropping tasks on you is terrible. (You're sure they don't communicate, right?)

I cannot tell for #6.

#7 reflects good management from the shareholders' point of view: underpay the employees, get lot's of production.

Bottom line, yes leave. You are at the point of complaining on the internet to strangers already. The management is bad, the code is a hot potato that will fall on someone in the future, and you're underpaid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, leave. There's always some degree of bias in "lists of what I hate about this team," but even the most charitable interpretation seems like a nightmare to me.

Again, please leave as soon as possible. You could easily burn out to the point where you are less effective at finding new, better opportunities.

As an aside, it's funny how low pay and poor management always seem to go hand-in-hand.